# Datagridview ColumnHeader alignment with cell data

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datagridcolumnheader

[image: picture of the full datagridview]

The column header with the number sign has a ridiculous amount of padding.

I've tried messing around with the ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle to no avail. Any ideas?

[image: close-up with annotated problem]

Comment: What are the current Column Layout properties?  They look evenly spaced in the screen shot.

Comment: @LarsTech [Here's some](http://puu.sh/ncYqL/9d42b0eacf.png) of the settings.

Comment: Padding is the space around the data in the cell - it is an interior thing.  You issue is just one of width

Comment: Does your grid use the DataSource property?  Otherwise, in the designer, go to Edit Columns, and view the Layout properties at the bottom of the property grid.

Comment: they look like they are auto generated column since they are all so evenly sized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if I understand the current form of the question, it goes like this:

[image]

Top image BAD - header text does not align with cell text.
Bottom image GOOD: text lines up

First, the header cells have different padding to allow room for the sizer handle and in some cases 3D effects.  To get your "title" cells to align with the header, add a little left `Padding`.  To get my "Active" column to line up I used:

```
dgv1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(2, 0, 0, 0)
```

For the right aligned header text you may be out of luck, this shows why:

[image]

The actual text area of the header cells are restrained to reserve room for the sort glyph.  If they didn't do so, the text would jump around as columns are sorted.  If you do not intend to let the user sort the data, you can set the column(s) to non sortable and it won't reserve room for the glyph:

```
dgv1.DataSource = dtSimple
dgv1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(0).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

dgv1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(1).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

dgv1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(2).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dgv1.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
```

Comment: anywhere after there is data in it.  Does your use a datasource?  Are the columns auto generated?

Comment: will try this in a moment. Been a long day. Currently working on a textbox with a "(Multiple values)" placeholder that detects a backstroke keypress.

Comment: this will have to do. If I wanted to sort the columns, I'd have to create a custom dgv and redraw the position, but that'll be going too far in depth. Thanks!